# How do I resolve the NuGet repository path via code?

Tags: nuget, nuget-package

I'm writing a NuGet package that needs to execute an .exe stored in the package itself.

I do not want to use content (and content and scripts are going away anyway)

So I want to be able to find the path to where my package is stored. How do I do that reliably now that the package folder can be changed by the user and nuget.config can be stored on multiple levels?

It is mentioned here:
http://blog.nuget.org/20150729/Introducing-nuget-uwp.html
.. " Simply find it from the .nuget path ..."

But there must be a utility for doing that right? Maybe one of the Nuget-libraries can resolve the path for me?

Comment: When do you plan to execute the exe? Is it a build time thing in msbuild?

Comment: No, from code - during unit tests or when in production

Comment: The packages don't necessarily exist in production. Looks like you are trying to indeed use something akin to content if you want to move the exe into the production environment as well. Or is your plan to restore packages on the target machine (if its a phone that is quite impossible). You could theoretically include a target file that will copy the exe over to the output path.

Comment: Ok, so actually only unit tests.

Should be similar to running PhantomJS.exe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no public api (properly support at least) to do it. But you could use the NuGet.Configuration from the myget feed - https://www.myget.org/gallery/nugetbuild

Create a settings object using this API -

```
var settings = Settings.LoadDefaultSettings(rootFolder, null, null);
```

See
https://github.com/NuGet/NuGet3/blob/dev/src/NuGet.Configuration/Settings/Settings.cs#L114

You might need to tweak the input to get it right, I didn't try it in a unit test.

Then get the global packages folder

```
 var path = SettingsUtility.GetGlobalPackagesFolder(settings)
```

Note that the packages is not in a stable form, and I expect changes going forward, at least after addressing this bug - https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/1098

Edit -

You can now just grab the package from nuget.org